# Live Wallpaper preferences in launcher

Tags: android, preferences, live-wallpaper

I'm developing a live wallpaper (just for me), and i wan't to access the preferences of my wallpaper with a icon on my homescreen. The preference activity is already declared in my manifest, and when i add the intent filter "android.intent.action.MAIN" with "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER", the icon shows. But when i click the icon it says that the app isn't installed.